# What happens if you create a git feature branch instead of release branch from a tag?

Tags: java, git, jenkins

I created a feature branch instead of release branch from a tag(2.4.1). It triggered auto release and did something, plus created a new tag 2.4.2. The confusion is which tag pointing to the latest version of dev? Is there a way to undo what I did? For which tag should I create a release branch to auto-deploy it?

Comment: *Git* doesn't care how you create a branch: you just pick some existing commit, and tell it *make new branch name that identifies this existing commit* and it's done. There's nothing else to it.

Comment: I'm not sure that this has anything to do with Java or Jenkins.  You can use git with pretty much any programming environment.

Comment: This is something that your project has developed in Jenkins, and it is not a standard well-knows configuration. I would recommend you to leave everything as is, because the environment should be robust to the case of invalid branch name.

Comment: By the way, there are no "release branches" or "feature branches". From the Git's point of view all branches are just branches with some fance names. This is Jenkins, GitHub or any other tool that uses Git who distinguishes the branches based on some naming pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing happens actually when you just create feature/release branches except that Git just pulls the code accordingly. If anything triggered a build, you must probably be talking about some CI/CD pipeline your DevOps team had set up. I would suggest creating a new feature branch from your previous tag(2.4.1) and start working. You can refer [this](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) for Git branching strategy and [this](https://dzone.com/articles/what-is-cicd) for understanding CI/CD.